# Messagebox for Web Forms 

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create a Messagebox in ASP.NET web forms?
I can't add `system.windows.form`.

Please help. I don't want to do it in javascript.

Comment: you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the difference between web and desktop (windows forms) programming

Comment: and also, apparently, about VB.NET/C# (which are two languages) and ASP.NET/Windows Forms. Both of the former are languages - and either of those languages can be used in either of the latter frameworks. (I add this due to the "but I can do this easily in VB" comment from the OP that is in one of the answers below)

Comment: Please do not include tags in the title of your questions.

Answer (score 8):

To pop-up a message box you use `alert()` in JavaScript.  You have to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: is there anyway without javascript?

Comment: No, there is no other way. The MessageBox will be created by the browser, hence you have to use client side scripting (JavaScript).

Comment: Wow... with 12.2k in points and there is no other way to show a message box in a web environment ? dang!!! a `div` with a `display:none` that if you do `<div id="myMsg" runat="server">` you can even do that on code-behind using `myMsg.Visible = true;` will work! No javascript here!

Comment: @balexandre, that's not the same as a message box IMO.

Comment: @Sam, at the end, it is a "message" "box" :)

Comment: @balexandre, it's a fragment of html that happens to show a message.  It's not a modal pop-up that the user has to acknowledge.

Comment: Agree with Sam. And besides, how would you "show" that hidden DIV without using JavaScript? A messagebox is a popup triggered by an event (client-side), setting it to Visible true on the server won't do any good - as it will either always be shown, or shown after a postback. Neither satisfies the behaviour of a messagebox.

Comment: @RPM1984 if you say `<div runat="server">` that becomes automatically a html control that you can do whatever you do with all other, even `myControl.visible = true;` you guys need more time on ASP.NET ;)

Comment: @balexandre - your missing the point completely. *Where* does that `myControl.visible = true` code go? At which point in time does that code execute?

Comment: And all `<div runat="server">` does is tell ASP.NET: "Hey, watch this control". And allows it to be accessed as a `HtmlGenericControl`. Show me some code where you can display a hidden div as popup without JavaScript and i will eat my words.

Comment: Hmm, no reply - maybe someone is out "spending more time on ASP.NET" :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) from the ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit.

Of course, behind the scenes, it uses JavaScript, but you don't have to write the JavaScript yourself.

Answer (score 3):

in web you have 2 chooices:

- create a div and show / hide it with the message
- use the alert or confirmation box with javascript

if you're using ASP.NET, and you want this kinda of things out-of-the-box I strongly suggest you to download and use the [**ASP.NET Toolkit**](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/)

you will see many solutions in the left side that you can use in your project and one of them is the [Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) ... check them out!